# How to sum up values of same field in array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects

```
const data = [
  { category: 'shopping', amount: 50 }, 
  { category: 'rent', amount: 1000 }, 
  { category: 'groceries', amount: 20 }, 
  { category: 'shopping', amount: 50 }
]
```

and I am trying to sum up the amounts per category

```
const result = [
  { category: 'shopping', amount: 100 },
  { category: 'rent', amount: 1000 },
  { category: 'groceries', amount: 20 }
]
```

So far, I'm thinking of removing the 'duplicates' of categories and store them into an array

```
const temp = data.map((obj) => {
  return obj.category
})

const categories = [...new Set(temp)] // ['shopping','rent','groceries']
```

With the above, i'm thinking of doing a nested loop but after many tries, I have failed.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to do that.

Iterate on given data and if an item with same `category` as current item exists, then add the `amount`, else add current item as a new entry.

```js
const data = [
  { category: 'shopping', amount: 50 }, 
  { category: 'rent', amount: 1000 }, 
  { category: 'groceries', amount: 20 }, 
  { category: 'shopping', amount: 50 }
];

let result = data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  let item = acc.find(item => item.category === curr.category);

  if (item) {
    item.amount += curr.amount;
  } else {
    acc.push(curr);
  }

  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Here is an alternative approach using object as the accumulator. This has a performance benefit as we wouldn't have to call `find()` on every iteration. Credits to [frodo2975](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2095953/frodo2975) for the suggestion.

```js
const data = [
  { category: 'shopping', amount: 50 }, 
  { category: 'rent', amount: 1000 }, 
  { category: 'groceries', amount: 20 }, 
  { category: 'shopping', amount: 50 }
];

let result = Object.values(data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  let item = acc[curr.category];

  if (item) {
    item.amount += curr.amount;
  } else {
    acc[curr.category] = curr;
  }

  return acc;
}, {}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: You can get better performance by accumulating into an object rather than an array, so that you don't have to call `.find` for every item. Then, you can use Object.entries to convert back to an array.

Comment: Thanks @frodo2975.  Added this as an alternative in the answer.

Comment: Thanks guys, this helped. I haven't had much experience with the reduce method as it is a bit confusing @_@

Comment: You're welcome @LeonChung. I'm glad it helped. Yes, it would be confusing at first but you'll get better as you progress.

Comment: @Nikhil coming back to this, could you elaborate why I need the `item` variable?

can't i create an object inside the function and push it directly into the accumulator? or am I understanding the method wrong

Comment: @LeonChung - You can directly use and modify the accumulator without creating `item` variable, StepUp's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58614368/2924577) does exactly that. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

I would focus on efficiently computing the totals for each category, and then restructuring the data in the format that you need. So something like this:

```js
// Construct an object mapping category to total amount.
const totals = data.reduce((totals, { category, amount }) => {
    totals[category] = (totals[category] || 0) + amount;
}, {});

// Format the data as you like.
const result = Object.entries(totals).map(([category, amount]) => ({ category, amount });
```

Answer (score 2):

Just another version of using `reduce` method:)

```js
const data = [
  { category: 'shopping', amount: 50 },
  { category: 'rent', amount: 1000 },
  { category: 'groceries', amount: 20 },
  { category: 'shopping', amount: 50 }
];

const result = data.reduce((a,c) => {
  a[c.category] = a[c.category] || {category: c.category, amount: 0};
  a[c.category].amount += c.amount;
  return a;
}, {})

console.log(Object.values(result));
```